# enable p:commandlink button when all checkbox are checked

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

In my page I have three checkbox , I want to enable submit button when all the checkbox are checked

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check2" />

<p:commandLink id="reviewLink" update="messages" ajax="false" action="${reviewBean.approveAndSubmitWorkflow}"   value="#msg['review.label.button.approve.submit']}"></p:commandLink>
```

Comment: what is the equivalent HTML for this `commandLink`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("input.check").change(function(){
    if ($('input.check:checked').length == $('input.check').length) {
       $('#reviewLink').prop('disabled' , false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($( "input:checked").length==3){    
  $('#reviewLink').prop('disabled',false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**

> IT is very Simple

**

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check1" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check2" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check3" />
    <script>
    // Disable submit button
    $("#submitButton").attr('disabled','disabled');

    // Handle event
$("#check1, #check2, #check3").live("change",function(){
 // Make a check
    if ($('#check1').is(':checked') && $('#check2').is(':checked') && $('#check3').is(':checked')){
    $("#submitButton").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})

    </script>
```